# Where can I find LexerGrammar API in ANTLR

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I would like to use LexerInterpreter in the ANTLR as in below link
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+and+lexer+interpreters

However, with ANTLR4 runtime assemblies (.Net), LexerGrammar and Grammar APIs are not recognized. Where can I find them ? Did I miss any reference assemblies.

Thank You,

Comment: The `Grammar` class is not part of the ANTLR 4 Runtime. As of today, only the runtime components were ported to other languages. However, that could change if someone contributes a port of the tool as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information Sam Hawell.

Comment: Sam,                                                                                                         Work done by you and Terrace Par in ANTLR is incredible.

Comment: As LexerInterpreter is available with C# Antlr4.Runtime, is there any blog post on how to use this without the Grammar and Lexer/ParserGrammar